kill kde "resume" feature
when I have the kind of problem that forces me to reboot, I log back in, and debian+kde helpfully starts up every program it thinks I want to resume. This is, of course, precisely the opposite of why I rebooted - maybe Dolphin is trying to view a folder that's hard to access, which maybe caused the issue. Maybe firefox ran away with ram on some web page. Maybe some hardware driver fails to load hanging the settings app. So the point of rebooting is to start fresh - but on log in, KDE helpfully pulls up all the potentially problematic apps and flings them all in my face, potentially putting the system right back in whatever state made me want to reboot in the first place. Is there some way to turn this off?
